# Is it better to save a wysiwyg created content to file or database?

Tags: laravel, database, backend, wysiwyg

I am not sure, it seems to be a common practice to save the HTML directly in the database, but i have the impression that saving a full HTML embedded with images could negatively affect the database overall performance. Is saving just a file path to a HTML file a better solution? Which would be the advantages or disadvantages of one solution over another?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to save the content directly to database, with lognText column
About images, you can store it in storage and just get the path inside database

No need to save it in files